# Can the mutual information be larger than the joint entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

For a Gaussian random variable of unitary variance, the entropy is given by
$H = 0.5\log(2 \pi e)$. Also, the mutual information (MI) between correlated Gaussian random variables is given by $MI = -0.5\log(1 - \rho^2)$, where $\rho$ denotes correlation. With these equations in mind, I can think of values for $\rho$ with which the MI is larger than the joint entropy between the two random variables. Am I missing something here or the MI may indeed be larger than the joint entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a Gaussian random variable of unitary variance, the entropy is given by $H=0.5 \log(2 \pi e)$.

Not quite. That's the **differential entropy**, which is a very different thing from the Shannon entropy.
You cannot compare in a meaningful mutual information with differential entropies.

In particular, calling $h()$ the differential entropies, it's true that

$$I(X;Y) = h(X) - h(X|Y)$$

but it's not true that  $h(X|Y) \ge 0$. Hence, the mutual information can be larger that the (differential) entropy of any variable (or the joint two variables).

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454078/non-zero-conditional-differential-entropy-between-a-random-variable-and-a-functi/1301569#1301569) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398438/differential-entropy/1398471#1398471) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880612/comparing-differential-entropy-of-normal-distribution-to-shannon-entropy/2880947#2880947)...